# What does opening/closing curly braces without any keyword mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I just saw this little piece of code and now I'm a bit curious about the meaning of that... is it just used for code indentation?

```
form_buffer('start');
{
  form_validation();
}
form_buffer('end');
```

Comment: plain nothing. it helps structuring but IMO it does not improve readability

Comment: In some other languages you can scope variables this way because variables defined inside the block is available only there, but PHP doesn't do variable scoping like that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it could be just personal notation from the developer.